# Customizing Validate Node Error Message in OSB 12c

Tags: xsd, osb

When we add the Validate Node in the OSB 12c for validating the incoming request against XSD, and if the validation fails , 
in some fault messages the field name that is causing the validation error is displayed. But only for decimal values , fault message is just saying Invalid decimal Value and no mention about the field from where the error is thrown. Can we overcome this issue

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is direct solution. But there is a workaround which may suit your need

Create an XQuery which validates the payload and throws custom error messages

eg: for xml element which should contain decimal value abc

`if ($a instance of xs:long)
then ()
else (fn:error(xs:QName('Your error code'), 'your error message'))`

This is a suitable method if the payload is small.

https://gibaholms.wordpress.com/2013/09/24/osb-throw-exception-in-xquery[1](https://gibaholms.wordpress.com/2013/09/24/osb-throw-exception-in-xquery/)

If the payload is large

1. identify the fields which are supposed to have these type of issues.
2. Create an XQuery for validating these fields with error messages.
3. Use validate node inside a stage and use a stage error handler
4. Validate the payload using xquery inside stage error handler